# Directly jump to the last position in android recyclerview rather than scrolling through to the last position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an Android heterogenous RecyclerView where I have ImageView and TextView mixed together. I could add either an image or Text on demand in the last position. If the user is already in the last item of the RecyclerView this isn't an issue, since the new text or image is simply appended and shows up as the new last item, which the user could immediately view.

But here is the trouble:
   Say I have 100 images in the RecyclerView and the user is viewing the very first image (at the top of the RecyclerView). Say the user adds a new image or text (which gets appended as the last item). Now in order to show this item to the user, I am calling "smoothScrollToPosition" as shown in the code below:

```
int position = myModel.getMyGenericModels().size() - 1;
myAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
//Smooth scroll the recyclerview to the last message
myRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

smoothScrollToPosition does work, but the trouble with this logic is:
   Given the user is viewing the very first image, in order to show the latest image added, the RecyclerView scrolls through all the 100 images until it reaches the last image. This is so awkward because it takes a few seconds and you can literally see these images scrolling up the screen until it reaches the last image.

My question is, how do I rather directly jump from the first image the user is viewing to show the user the last image that was added?

To be clear the kind of behavior I am looking for is like the one exhibited by Android WhatsApp client. Say you are on a chat screen and you are on the top message, but now add a new image or message, you could see it magically jump to the bottom of the screen showing the last message added. There is none of this explicit awkward scroll through all the messages - so that seems possible, but I don't know how. I wonder how that is being done.

Comment: Does it have to be added into the last position?

Comment: Yes, that is the functionality I need.

Comment: What is exactly is wrong with `scrollToPosition`?

Comment: Please read my post where I have pointed out the issue. scrollToPosition does work, but the trouble with this logic is: Given the user is viewing the very first image, in order to show the latest image added, the RecyclerView scrolls through all the 100 images until it reaches the last image. This is so awkward because it takes a few seconds and you can literally see these images scrolling up the screen until it reaches the last image.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that I was using smoothScrollToPosition.

Comment: In your post you specifically said: I have searched online for a solution, but only coming across suggestions to use "scrollToPosition" or "smoothScrollToPosition", which does the above awkward behavior.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the confusion caused. I had somehow arrived at the wrong conclusion that smoothScrollToPosition and scrollToPosition were synonymous and I was indeed using smoothScrollToPosition like shown in the sample code. Let me get the question edited to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scrollToPosition` is the one you are looking for.

- `smoothScrollToPositon` is loading the views in between the current and the position it is scrolling to with an animation so this will take a relatively long time scrolling to the specified position.
- `scrollToPosition` is different as it only loads the view at the specified position and the views after or before it based on the direction.

## Example

This is a RecyvlerView

```
Item 0  ---
Item 1    |
Item 2    | Those appearing on screen
Item 3  ---
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8
Item 9
```

**smoothScrollToPosition(9)** will load items 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 one by one with a scroll to the end.

**scrollToPosition(9)** will only load items 6, 7, 8, 9 one by one with a scroll to the end.

I think the confusion comes from the scroll animation you get from using `scrollToPosition`, but it's a kinda necessary thing because if not you will wait until all views are painted to scroll to the specified position. It loads the first item from the new list and scrolls on from the end of the currently displayed list items.

Comment: Awesome illustration and explanation. I wish I had illustrated this using the simple pictorial representation you did! Ah, I see. I was indeed using "smoothScrollToPosition" and blindly assuming that it is the same as "scrollToPosition". Big mistake. Now I changed it to scrollToPosition and the behavior is definitely much better. But like you describe we could still see the scroll happen and it isn't a "Snap to position" like it happens in WhatsApp android client  (of course they are their own league). But somehow they seem to be doing it.

Comment: scrollToPosition is much better, but still it isn't a "snap to position" behavior that I see in WhatsApp. But it does solve the awkward scroll through of the smooth scroll, which will be a blocker for the functionality I intent.